# WCF use SoapUi to mock services with wsdl

Tags: wcf, soapui

I'm trying to use the wsdl of my wcf web service with SoapUi 5.2.1 with not luck. When i create a SoapUi project with the wsdl nothing happens, no errors or nothing and none of the web operations are mocked out. Has anyone seen this happen before? I have an endpiont for IMetadata define in the web config

And httpGetEnabled set to true

From what I know that should be all you need to expose the metadata correct? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you open the wsdl in a internet browser? Have you happened to check soapui logs ?Otherwise, try to run `SOAPUI_HOME\bin\soapui.bat` from command line, then try import wsdl to see what is happening.

Comment: it looks fine in the browser. I haven't looked at the logs, soapui wasn't throwing an error so I didn't think to. I'll that .bat and see what happens. thank you for your help!